# iOS Asset/Storyboards not updating unless a "Clean Build" Swift package manager, Xcode, Storyboards, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift-package-manager

TLDR;
Assets(storyboards, images) not updating unless clean build with Swift package manager local dependency.

**Explanation:**

I use Swift package manager and have a local dependency (module) that has storyboards, image assets etc. However, if I make any change on them and just `cmd+r` to run the app, changes are not shown; for example, if I change label text on the storyboard, it won't show the updated text if I just run `cmd+r`.

To make them appear, I have to clean the build folder and re-run the app again.
But if I change any swift file it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try just going to file>Packages>Update Packages To Latest Version

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar behavior with one of my projects. Changes to the storyboard wouldn't be reflected in the simulator if I chose the ****new build system****.

I know that the **legacy build system** is now deprecated, but you can still try to build with it and see if it is a bug of the new build system.

File > Project settings (or Workspace settings) > Build System > Legacy Build System

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating the packages and also delete your derived Data and archives and give it a go. Seems more of a Xcode bug /cashe issue . Are you using Xcode 13?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find the exact reason because it could depend on several factors. When you open your storyboard file, go to ***Editor->Automatically Refresh Designable Views*** and be sure it's checked.
Check also ***Xcode->Preferences->General->Issues*** and be sure the check below called "**Show Live Issues**" is flagged as this picture:

[image]

Another reason about your assets refresh failure could depend by the missing resources inside the list: ***Targets->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources***

Check also if your resources are shared with a file hosting service like Dropbox, it could be have a local cache which keeps the old version.